# Spring Batch + Kafka: KafkaItemReader run forever?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-batch

I want to make something to monitor some Kafka topic continuously, and then execute some batch job when a message comes in (hitting some REST api and storing response).  I set something up with KafkaItemReader, however, it turns off if it doesn't receive a message for 30 seconds based on pollTimeout.  How can I make it run indefinitely? Since this is not an obvious option I'm wondering if I am using the right tool for the job.

Comment: Likely answer: you are not supposed to do this.  KafkaItemReader is meant for cases where you want to do a one-off read of currently available messages on the Kafka topic given some other trigger (e.g. a scheduler).  It's not the correct way to continuously monitor the topic.  I ended up solving my problem using a simple Kafka listener calling an @Async helper.

Answer (score 1):

> Likely answer: you are not supposed to do this.

That's correct. Batch processing is about processing finite data sets. If your data source is an infinite stream of records and you want to monitor it continuously, then a streaming solution is more appropriate for your use case.